# Writing regular expressions for these languages?

Tags: regex, theory, regular-language

The following languages over the alphabet Σ = {0, 1} are all regular:

> L = { w | w is of even length and begins with 01 }
>
> L = { w | the numbers of 1's in w is multiple of 3 }
>
> L = { w | w does not contain the substring 10 }

I am asked to write regular expressions for these languages, but I don't know how to do so. Can anyone give me advice on how to approach these problems?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like an attempt to get us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am new to this and can't understand the rules of regular expressions.

Comment: @HamZa: Nice. In my culture, it is Fall that is indicated by the coming of the HW.

Comment: Sorry, I thought here people's are more active than being talkative, as I don't have much time to know about this topics, I think, you people'll be helpful but in vain

Comment: @Light- As someone currently teaching a course in computability theory, I'm very concerned about academic honesty and integrity. We're happy to help *if you've demonstrated that you've made a good honest effort on your own*. Posting homework questions and saying "how do you solve these?" doesn't give any indication that you've made an effort, and just getting the solutions won't help. See my answer - which is a series of hints - for some intuitions.

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks for your help. I am not learning computability theory. I have needed some specific answers. But you people make me so stupid that I think, I ought to study on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> L = { w | w is of even length and begins with 01 }

**Ans:** `01((0 + 1)(0 + 1))*`

Explanation: `01` itself of even length to, we can suffix any even length string consist of `0`s and `1`s.

> L = { w | the numbers of 1's in w is multiple of 3 }

**Ans:** `(0*10*10*10*)*`

Explanation: `0` can appear any number of time anywhere in string the restriction is over `1` it should be in multiple of 3 so `*` over three `1`.

> L = { w | w does **not** contain the substring 10 }

**Ans:** `0*1*`

Explanation: string can't contain `10` means only `1` is allow after any `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. You can use the expression (0 ∪ 1) to mean "0 or 1," and (0 ∪ 1)(0 ∪ 1) to mean "any two-character string." Can you form all even-length regular expressions from the second of those expressions? Can you then see how to get from there to the language you need?
2. Any string with a number of 1s that's a multiple of three can be subdivided into a bunch of smaller strings, each of which consists of three 1s with 0's interspersed. Can you make all strings with exactly three 1's in them? From there, can you get the language you need?
3. This is actually the easiest of the bunch. Write out a few strings that don't contain 10. Notice anything? As a hint, you can do this with four characters.

Hope this helps!